# API Controller for creating new entities with DateTime

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a controller in Symfony2 (2.8) for calendar events but have some problems with the DateTime field. The controller is a api only controller, but uses the same entity and form as the "normal" controller.

In Ajax calls, I get a response that the value for the date time field is not valid. I tried to read up on it, and found that I needed to create a DataTransformer to transform it to a DateTime object and vice versa. When I add a `DataTransformer` to the calendar event form, "normal" create breaks. It seems that it transforms the value twice?

Removing the model transformer, and the "normal" create works, but Ajax continues to return not valid on start and end date time fields.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Resources I have read:
https://tech.enekochan.com/en/2015/11/21/symfony-forms-and-bootstrap-datetimepicker/
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html
and a couple of more I could not find right now.

Bellow is my code. Please let me know if I should post more information.

Thank you for your time.

My CalendarEvent entity looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CalendarEventRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="calendar_events")
 */
class CalendarEvent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, name="start")
     */
    private $start;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, name="end")
     */
    private $end;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="status")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true, name="description")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true, options={"default":0})
     */
    private $busy;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBusy()
    {
        return $this->busy;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $busy
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setBusy($busy)
    {
        $this->busy = $busy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set start
     *
     * @param \DateTime $start
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setStart($start)
    {
        $this->start = $start;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get start
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Set end
     *
     * @param \DateTime $end
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setEnd($end)
    {
        $this->end = $end;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get end
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param string $status
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return CalendarEvent
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

The CalendarEventType looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateTimeTransformer;

class CalendarEventType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct($date = null, $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
          ->add('name', null, array(
            'attr' => array(
              'placeholder' => 'app.forms.calendar.name',
            ),
            'label' => 'app.forms.calendar.name',
            'translation_domain' => 'AppBundle'
          ))
          ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label' => 'app.forms.calendar.description',
            'translation_domain' => 'AppBundle'
          ))
          ->add('start', DateTimeType::class, array(
             'label'              => 'app.forms.calendar.start',
             'translation_domain' => 'AppBundle',
             'date_widget' => 'single_text',
             'time_widget' => 'text'
           ))
           ->add('end', DateTimeType::class, array(
              'label'              => 'app.forms.calendar.end',
              'translation_domain' => 'AppBundle',
              'date_widget' => 'single_text',
              'time_widget' => 'text'
           ));

        $builder->get('start')->addModelTransformer(new DateTimeTransformer());
        $builder->get('end')->addModelTransformer(new DateTimeTransformer());
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CalendarEvent',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            // a unique key to help generate the secret token
            'intention'       => 'calendar_event',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_calendarevent';
    }
}
```

The DateTimeTransformer:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class DateTimeTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Transforms an object (DateTime) to a string.
     *
     * @param  \DateTime|null $datetime
     * @return string
     */
    public function reverseTransform($datetime)
    {
        if (null === $datetime) {
            return '';
        }

        return $datetime->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:ii');
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string to an object (DateTime).
     *
     * @param  string $datetime
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function transform($datetime)
    {
        // datetime optional
        if (!$datetime) {
            return null;
        }

        return date_create_from_format('yyyy-MM-dd', $datetime);
    }
}
```

The Controller (I include only the create function here):

```
/**
 * @Route("/events", name="api_event_create")
 * @Method("post")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return array
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $response = new Response();

    // Get logged in user if it exists, else return unauthorized status code
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if( ! ($user instanceof User)) {
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        $response->send();
    };

    // Handle the request
    // Get data from post
    $data = $request->request->get('appbundle_calendarevent');

    // Create new entity
    $entity = new CalendarEvent();

    // Create form
    $form = $this->createForm(new CalendarEventType('', $this->get('security.token_storage')), $entity);

    // Submit form data
    $form->submit($data);

    // Check if form is valid
    if($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $title = (array_key_exists('name', $data)) ? $data['name'] : 'Ny hendelse';
        $desc  = (array_key_exists('description', $data)) ? $data['description'] : NULL;

        $entity->setUser($user);
        $entity->setName($title);
        $entity->setDescription($desc);
        $entity->setStatus('normal');

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(201);
        $response->headers->set(
            'Location',
            $this->generateUrl('calendar_events_show', array('id' => $entity->getId()))
            );
    } else {
        return array('errors' => $form->getErrors());
    }

    $response->send();
}
```

The Javascript for Ajax calls:

```
(function($){
    $('.calendar td').on('dblclick', function() {
        var self = $(this);
        newEvent(self).done(handleDone);
    });

    var newEvent = function(self) {
        var url = 'url to api';
        var method = 'post';
        var selectedDate = self.attr('id');
        var eventStartDate = moment(selectedDate, "YYYYMMDD").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); // Start date
        var eventEndDate   = moment(selectedDate, "YYYYMMDD").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); // End date

        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            data: {
                "appbundle_calendarevent[name]": 'New event',
                "appbundle_calendarevent[start]": eventStartDate,
                "appbundle_calendarevent[end]": eventEndDate,
                "appbundle_calendarevent[_token]": form_token
            },
            statusCode: {
                400: handleStatus400,
                401: handleStatus401,
                402: handleStatus402,
                404: handleStatus404,
                422: handleStatus422,
                500: handleStatus500
            }
        });
    };

    function handleDone(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    function handleStatus400() {
        console.log('400');
    }

    function handleStatus401() {
        console.log('401');
    }

    function handleStatus402() {
        console.log('402');
    }

    function handleStatus404() {
        console.log('404');
    }

    function handleStatus422() {
        console.log('422');
    }

    function handleStatus500() {
        console.log('500');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Making the Ajax call sends these parameters:

```
appbundle_calendarevent[name]:"New+event"
appbundle_calendarevent[start]:"2016-03-25+00:00"
appbundle_calendarevent[end]:"2016-03-25+00:00"
appbundle_calendarevent[_token]:"97Ygs8Q9y70gi0vs24Mrg1LfpCvZ2wjaIcc41KASjkg"
```

Comment: Instead of `date_create_from_format('yyyy-MM-dd', $datetime);` try `new \DateTime($datetime);`

Comment: I tried it, but alas, it did not work. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this could be solved without DateTimeTransformer. @LBA put me on a Google search witch brought me to this post: http://www.keithwatanabe.net/2013/12/24/symfony-2-annoying-issue-with-data-transformers-datetime-timezones-and-php-ini/.

Here is what I did:

First, I removed `DataTransformer` from `CalendarEntityType`.
Second, I updated Javascript and the parameter values like so:

```
var eventStartDate = moment(selectedDate, "YYYYMMDD").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+01:00');
var eventEndDate   = moment(selectedDate, "YYYYMMDD").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+01:00');
```

Guess it is a timezone issue. If someone knows how to solve this on the symfony side, I would gladly accept that as an answer.